# Multiline regex issue in PHP

Tags: php, regex

Consider the code below, why it is not working?

```
<?php

$str = "
<h4>
   title
</h4>
";

$result = preg_match_all ('/<h4>([\d\D])<\/h4>/mi', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably meant

```
$str = "
<h4>
   title
</h4>
";

$result = preg_match_all ('/<h4>(.+?)<\/h4>/si', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

The regex you applied, `'/<h4>([\d\D])<\/h4>/mi'`, means "Match an opening h4, **one character** that's either a digit or not a digit, and a closing h4." But you have plenty of characters to match, so you need to specify a quantifier ("more than one", `+`). **Update: you need a non-greedy quantifier, `+?`, if you have more than one h4 (very likely!)** And the class `[\d\D]` can be reduced to "any character", `.`. One more point: you need to use `/s` instead of `/m` to get the behaviour you want.

This will probably include the newlines in your match!

Comment: Maybe using .* instead of .+ in case of a empty node. Shouldn't be happening but depending on how HTML source is generated... mieux vaut prévenir que guérir

Comment: I removed the greediness, because that might match right up to the end tag of the very last h4 in the document! I hope to receive some feedback from Howard.

Comment: Will it "probably include the newlines in your match"; I had no idea the matching was a matter of probablies.

Comment: No, it isn't. I meant "My personal opinion is that it will include the newlines in your match, but I have too little experience with PHP's PCRE (and I didn't test it), so I'm not sure if this will happen!" You're invited (by me, but more importantly, by SO) to edit my answer and confirm or deny the statement, or comment on it explaining if this will happen.